# visual studio c# Connection String Issue

Tags: visual-studio

I seem to be unable to connect to the database via ASP.NET connection Manager.

The connection string which I am using is,

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="RiskRegister_Web" connectionString="server=########;UserId=RiskRegister;Password=#########;Database=RiskRegister_Web;Integrated Security=False;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When the connection manager comes up, it says cant connect to the database check data source, i have checked settings in `SQL` and been able to login as the user.

I'm wondering if my connection string is incorrect?

Comment: Try this connection string: connectionString="Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Initial Catalog=db_name;Data Source=#####;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: I was met with cant connect to sql database. on the welcome page it says Application:/ Current User Name:JTH\###########, does that have anything to do with the issue?

Comment: Using Sql management studio i have logged on as Riskregister and connected fine. and was able to query the tables built by aspnet_regsql.exe also using the same logon details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't have the other necessary information in my web.config file below to connect to the asp.net configuration correctly.

> ```
> <profile defaultProvider="profileSqlProvider"  >
>       <providers>
>        <clear />
>           <add
> name="profileSqlProvider"
> type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
> connectionStringName="RiskRegister_Security"
> applicationName="RiskRegister"
> description="SqlProfileProvider for RiskRegister" />
>       </providers>
>       <properties>
>           <add name="UserClassification"   />
>           <add name="Country"   />
>       </properties>
>   </profile>
>   <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="roleSqlProvider">
>       <providers>
>           <clear />
>           <add
> name="roleSqlProvider"
> type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
> connectionStringName="RiskRegister_Security"
> applicationName="RiskRegister" />
>       </providers>
>   </roleManager>
>   <membership defaultProvider="membershipSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
>       <providers>
>           <clear />
>           <add
> name="membershipSqlProvider"
> type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
> connectionStringName="RiskRegister_Security"
> applicationName="RiskRegister"
> enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
> enablePasswordReset="true"
> requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
> requiresUniqueEmail="true"
> passwordFormat="Hashed" />
>       </providers>
>   </membership>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `;Connect Timeout=30` to your `connectionString`.

Comment: It may be easier to open the Server Explorer, add a new connection, fill in your settings, test the settings, and open the Advanced options. You can copy and paste the connectionString from the bottom of that screen.

Comment: Connected fine using server explorer copied settings. Connection failed